# Can Swagger UI for Spring hide some HTTP method

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger-ui

I integrated my Spring mvc project with the Swagger UI. For those 'views' that are not set the 'method' as the parameter in the annotation '@RequestMapping', Swagger UI shows all Http method in its doc page.[image]

My question is can i customize this, what i want is for those views set the 'method' in '@RequestMapping', Swagger could show those Http method type, But for those not set, Swagger only shows GET method.

Comment: are you using swagger 2, if yes i believe  you can customize and write the code in SwaggerConfiguration file

Comment: Yeah, i'm using swagger 2. Is there any tutorial or useful link about the 'SwaggerConfiguration' that you said. Thanks.

Comment: I don;t have any specific link but you can check for SwaggerFilter , but get help from https://github.com/springfox/springfox/